# Prime Number Count

Tags: python, function, loops

```
def prime_count(a, b):
    for i in range(a,b):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            return sum(i)
        else:
          return 0 "
```

I am trying to count how many prime numbers are on `a` and `b`, they are already integers and there is no user input.

I am not very good at loops yet and thought this was going to be a good challenge to practice, what am I doing wrong? I keep getting `int object is not iterable`

For reference, here is the link for the challenge: https://edabit.com/challenge/6QYwhZstMuHYtZRbT

Comment: You are calling `sum()`, a built-in that takes an iterable, with an integer (not iterable) argument. Also, can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? This does not appear to count prime numbers to me.

Comment: I am trying to iterate through ```a``` and  ```b```. Both are supposed to be integers, such as ```(1,10)``` so then I would iterate through ```(1,10)``` and return how many prime numbers were in the range of ```(1,10)```.

Comment: Prime numbers are natural numbers with only 1 and themselves as divisors. Therefore, you need to create a loop that goes through and divides each number by all other numbers between itself and 2, and then counts it as a prime number or not, depending on the result. You can't call sum on an integer, and you need to modify the logic of your function.

Comment: What are you expecting `sum(i)` to do?

Comment: I am expecting ```sum(i)``` to return the count of prime numbers.

Comment: `sum` is a built in that works on a sequence or iterable object to return its sum. Therefore it cannot return a count of prime numbers. You need to do that yourself with the function logic.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run two-loops here. One to iterate from a to b and the inner loop to check if each element in a -->b is prime or not (the inner loop should run from 2 to j in [a,b).

```
def primecheck(a,b):
printlist=[]
if a > 1:
    for i in range(a,b+1):
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            printlist.append(i)
if len(printlist) == 0:
    return 0
else:
    return len(printlist), printlist
```

Answer (score 0):

As people say in the comment section, calling `sum()` is what's causing an error.

But, even if you somehow got that part right, you wouldn't quite get what you want. Maybe you were just trying a simple for loop to check if numbers are odd...?

Anyway, I normally like using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to generate prime numbers because it's simple.

```
def sieve_of_eratosthenes(start, end):
    if start > end:
        raise AssertionError
    
#     end = end + 1 # If end is inclusive, then uncomment this line.
    if end < 2:
        return 0
    
    sieve = [i for i in range(2, end)] # Initialize an array of number from 2 to end.
    size = len(sieve)
    p = 2 # Initial prime.
    count = 0

    # This block implements Sieve of Eratosthenes.
    while count < size:
        for i in range(count, size):
            num = sieve[i]
            if num != p and num % p == 0:
                sieve[i] = 0

        if count == size-1:
            break
        
        count += 1
        while sieve[count] == 0:
            count += 1
            if count == size-1:
                break
        p = sieve[count] # Update the next prime.
     
    # This block calculates the numbers of primes between start and end.
    num_of_primes = 0
    for p in sieve:
        if p == 0 or p < start:
            continue
        num_of_primes += 1
        
    print(sieve)
    return num_of_primes


sieve_of_eratosthenes(1, 100) # This should return 25.
```