# I have an issue with a Python code . The entry displays [*] when the code is executed

Tags: python

The question for my python code is as below:

COUNT PRIMES: Write a function that returns the number of prime numbers that exist up to and including a given number

My code is as below:

```
    def count_primes(num):
        lista = [3]
        b = 4
        while b <= num:
            for a in range(2,b-1):
                if b%a != 0:
                    lista.append(b)
                    b += 1
        return len(lista)
```

I got a problem displaying [*] in the entry
So I click "Kernel" and then "Interrupt" .

The traceback shows that this below line has an issue:

```
for a in range(2,b-1)
```

I found the answer for the question, but I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Can you please help me ?

Thank you

The traceback is as below:

```
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ea1b44fd7e05> in <module>
----> 1 count_primes(15)

<ipython-input-3-d9c02d7f375d> in count_primes(num)
      3     b = 4
      4     while b <= num:
----> 5         for a in range(2,b-1):
      6             if b%a != 0:
      7                 lista.append(b)

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Comment: What is the actual error that is thrown? Can you post post the entire trace?

Comment: You question / error is not clear, and you probably have many prime question in SO, have a look and give details please.

Comment: It seems you have a kind of infinite loop ...

Comment: Hello I have just added the full traceback again to the original post.

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt means you have been obliged to stop the program. The error is that the program does not stop or is too long. Not necessarily the exact line shown in the trace.

Comment: can you be more specific on which part of the code ? which changes should I make ? Thank you

Comment: in the code, b should stop when it reaches the value of num

Comment: Please search in the forum, same question as here : you can look at the Sieve of Eratosthenes algo to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65713366/python-beginner-question-prime-number-count

Answer (score 0):

The main culprit is that you are incrementing b in the condition in the inner loop. In the first iteration of your code, b = 4 and a  = 2.
Therefore b % a == 0. Therefore, the control never reaches the part where b is incremented and thus, the code is stuck in an infinite loop.
You may be thinking that when a = 3, that condition should be satisfied. However, since the loop is

```
for a in range(2, b - 1)
```

the values a can take when b = 4 is only 2.

Answer (score 0):

after trying to modify my code, I found the correct one. Thank you for your help.

```
def count_primes(num):
        lista = [3]
        b = 4
        while b <= num:
            for a in range(2,b):
                if b%a != 0 and a != (b-1):
                    continue
                elif b%a != 0 and a == (b-1):
                    lista.append(b)
                else:
                    break
            b += 1
        return len(lista)
```